# Onclick function for all members of a class

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, closures

I'm making a two-column math page, with theorems and definitions on the left side, and additional explanations on the right side.

The way that the user accesses the explanations is by clicking on text of the class "explainable".

After the page loads, I run a script to give each "explainable" element its own onclick function, which hides the text on the right panel (if any) and refills it with the clicked's elements explanation.

But when I try and run it, it tells me that the explainable element is undefined.

Here is the relevant function and an example of the text with the class:

**function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(makeExplanations, 3000);
    function makeExplanations(){
        var explainables = document.getElementsByClassName("explainable");
        var currentlyShowing = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < explainables.length; i++){
            console.log("id: " + explainables[i].id);
            var element = explainables[i];
            explainables[i].onclick = function(){
                if(currentlyShowing != ""){
                    document.getElementById(currentlyShowing + 'e').style.display = "none";
                }
                var explanationDiv = document.getElementById(explainables[i].id + 'e')
                explanationDiv.style.display = "inline";
                explanationDiv.focus();
                currentlyShowing = explainables[i].id;

            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have it waiting 3 seconds to execute because doing `body onload=makeExplainables()` wasn't sufficient. (Might have something to do with the way that the MathJax loads - I'm not sure.)

**example of explainable class**

```
<span class="explainable" id="595858535"><a href="#top">so either statement is vacuously true</a></span>. Thus, $X = Y$ holds, 
and hence we declare that there exists only one set with no elements.</p>
```

**and the explanation it reveals**

```
<div id="595858535e" style="display: none;">
    <p>An if-then statement (a conditional) is vacuously true when the if portion is false in all cases.
    For example, the statement "If 2 + 2 = 5, then pigs fly" is vacuously true, since its
    antecedent (if 2 + 2 = 5) is always false.</p>

    <p>In this case, the conditional in question is "there exists some $x \in X$ such that $x \notin Y$".
    But since $X$ is an empty set, there does not exist any $x \in X$ such that anything. Hence, the
    statement is vacuously true in all cases.</p>

    <p>Another way to think about it is this: a conditional is only falsified if its antecedent ("if ...") is true
    and its consequent ("then ... ") is false. If the antecedent is always false, then this can never happen.
    Thus the statement as a whole is always true.</p>
</div>
```

**Error in Firebug when I try to click on the explainable text**:

```
16:23:44.704 "id: 595858535" zfc:89
16:23:44.704 "id: 595858536" zfc:89
16:23:53.045 TypeError: explainables[i] is undefined zfc:95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason for that error is that "i" has already reached a value equal to the array's length, when the click handler is called. Hence explainables[i], i.e. explainables[explainables.length] is undefinded.

JS fiddle with console logs to explain you better: http://jsfiddle.net/wV4Lh/6/

```
        element.onclick = function(){
            // length of array is 2 for this example
            console.log("explainables length: " + explainables.length);                
            // value of i is 2 in the click handler
            console.log("i: " + i);
            // explainables[i] = explainables[2] is undefined
            console.log("explainables[i] - ith: " + explainables[i]);
            // explainables[0] is valid
            console.log("explainables[0] - 0th: " + explainables[0]);
            // explainables[1] is valid
            console.log("explainables[1] - 1st: " + explainables[1]);
        };
```

This clearly shows that explainables is well in scope of the click handler, but value of i = length of the array as the 'for' loop has already completed it's full execution way before the click event is triggered.

P.S: The difficulty in initially understanding this behavior of a handler is due the counter-intuitive way a handler works, i.e. it is not executed in sequence with other code surrounding it. A handler only get's executed when corresponding event is triggered and not in sequence with in the for loop, in this case.

Comment: So the only way to have each handler be triggered on the correct explainables[i] is to use `this` instead, like I did above? In other words, the variable is in the scope, but the value isn't different for each handler because they're all just referencing the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally got it work by changing the `explanation[i]` in the onclick function to `this`.

I thought that I was making a closure wherein the `explanation[i]` variable would be accessible from within the onclick function even after `makeExplanations()` ended, but I guess that is incorrect.

The corrected onclick function looks like this:

```
explainables[i].onclick = function(){
    if(currentlyShowing != ""){
        document.getElementById(currentlyShowing + 'e').style.display = "none";
    }
    var explanationDiv = document.getElementById(this.id + 'e')
    explanationDiv.style.display = "inline";
    explanationDiv.focus();
    currentlyShowing = this.id;

};
```

Comment: If someone more knowledgeable wants to give a better explanation of why what I tried to do didn't work, I'll be happy to give it the check.

Comment: Inside the method call, the object that contains it is referred to as `this`. In that scope, there is no explainables[i] object, unless it were defined in that method.